# enable PuTTY users to have X11 forwarding (Redhat 5 server)

Tags: terminal, putty, redhat-enterprise-linux, x11-forwarding

I want to enable graphical forwarding for my server.  I am connecting via PuTTY and click the X11 forwarding, which works with other servers.  None of the other topics on this site have helped me so far but I tried looking around.  Can anyone help?  Thanks.

```
[lkatz@localhost ~]$ echo $DISPLAY
localhost:10.0
```

On the Redhat server in question, I edited /etc/ssh/sshd_config to include the following lines (per another site's instructions):

```
AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
X11UseLocalhost yes
```

However when I try a graphical program via PuTTY on Windows I get these error messages:

```
[lkatz@localhost ~]$ gedit
The application 'gedit' lost its connection to the display localhost:10.0;
most likely the X server was shut down or you killed/destroyed
the application.
[lkatz@localhost ~]$ Mauve
X connection to localhost:10.0 broken (explicit kill or server shutdown).
[lkatz@localhost ~]$ gnome-terminal
The application 'gnome-terminal' lost its connection to the display localhost:10.0;
most likely the X server was shut down or you killed/destroyed
the application.
```

Answer (score 2):

- Make sure you have *xorg-x11-xauth* installed.
- Check SSH logs (PuTTY: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+right-click, choose "Event log").

Answer (score 2):

Do not forget to start your Windows X server.

I am using XMing and it's working fine from a computer running Debian 6.0.

Your configuration seems to be okay, by the way.